# Updating the ArangoDB collection from csv

Tags: arangodb

I'm just new to ArangoDB, so could you give me any tips how I can perform the following update?

I have the document collection, each document has a attribute `seen`. I want to update the existing collection from a csv-file in the following way: if in the file there is a line with `_key` that already is in the collection, I want to sum the `seen` value from csv-file and from the collection and replace the value in the collection by the sum; if there is no document with such `_key`, I just want to add it.

As far as I know, it is a little bit too much for the `arangoimp` tool, as it has an option either to replace or ignore dublicates.

How would you do that?

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, it's too much to ask from the `arangoimp` tool. You could use it to update existing records via `_key` and replace the `seen` attribute and create new documents it the `_key` does not exist yet. But it doesn't support to add logic that would sum up the seen values.

However, you can import your CSV with `arangoimp` to a temporary collection and use an AQL query to do that. Let `temp` be that temporary collection and `coll` your main collection:

```
FOR doc IN temp
  UPSERT { _key: doc._key }
  INSERT doc
  UPDATE { seen: OLD.seen + doc.seen }
  IN coll
```

You could optionally REPLACE instead of UPDATE or MERGE() the existing document with attributes from the imported document if needed, or remove the temp documents at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. While waiting here, I thought exactly about the same, and it works just fine for a 'small' collection of 200k documents. But then I tried to do the same for the other collection (edges collection this time) the size of 4 million documents, and it worked for 15 minutes without any result. That's too much in my case.

Comment: I've just found out that if I take a csv of the same size, but for the edge collection and perform the same query, it takes about 10 times longer to execute. Probably it's because of some features of this type of collection?

Comment: Does the temporary collection come with `_from` and `_to` attributes for the edge collection? Edge collections are definitely more expensive because of the additional edge index that needs to be maintained. I'm not sure if 10x slower is normal however.

Comment: Yes, both the temporary and the main collections have 3 attributes: `_from`, `_to` and `seen`. Documents with equal edge index in different collections have different `_key`. If I manage to make them equal, could this help, in your opinion?

Comment: Well, it actually helped. I used to do `UPSERT { _from: edge._from, _to: edge._to } ` and it took god knows how long, but when I do `UPSERT { _key:edge._key } ` it takes 190s for 4mil writes. I tried to do the same, but with document collections, and it took about 160s, so I guess, it couldn't be faster than that. The only question now is how I should generate a key for a pair `_from`-`_to`, but that's another story. Thank you again!

Comment: If you UPSERT using `_key`, does the query explain output say something about an optimization _patch-update-statements_? Does it show if you use `_from` and `_to` instead? It's possible that some optimization can only be applied in the former case, or the lookups in the edge index are way slower than using the primary key, which could explain the difference in performance.